# Reporting data into Qlikview dynamically from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, qlikview

I am currently working on an IT helpdesk application (MANAGE ENGINE) which uses a SQL Server 2005 backend; I would like to dynamically produce data with a chart. How do I create a chart in Qlikview with the two (2) columns in my SELECT statement as the X and Y axes?
Anytime I try creating charts, it automatically gives 3 options (sum, average or count). Can it just pick the values from the fields directly without doing any calculation on it?

Please find attached an example of the sheet I am interested in building.

Many thanks for your audience.

Kind Regards,
Tunde

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a chart with unprocessed X and Y values you need to set the only "dimension" of the chart to be the X value. Then for the Y values add an "expression" that is just equal to the name of the Y values without a function.

So say you had a table like

```
Owner, NoOfCalls
Alice, 4
Bob, 8
Chris, 9
```

The dimension of the chart would be Owner and you can select this using the drop down. On the expressions tab add an expression that is just

```
=NoOfCalls
```